# highcharts canvas-tools: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I've got a ruby-on-rails app where I'm trying to use highcharts/modules/canvas-tools.js.  I inheretid this app and the highcharts files aren't present within it.  I don't know much about javascript so I'm not even sure how the app uses the assets.  The page that should display the charts doesn't.  I get the following error in my Chrome console when trying to view the charts:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

The console refers to these lines:

```
// Extend CanVG renderer on demand, inherit from SVGRenderer
extend(CanVGRenderer.prototype, SVGRenderer.prototype);
```

and at the end of the highcharts file:

```
}(Highcharts));
```

Here's my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require highcharts
//= require highcharts/modules/canvas-tools
//= require highcharts/modules/exporting
//= require bootstrap-typeahead
//= require rails
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function()     {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
} );

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popover-myasset').popover();
});
```

In other cases I've gotten an error that says highcharts was loaded more than once, but I'm not using Highstock, which is apparently the source of this error. Link to error message:  http://highcharts.com/errors/16

Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Comment: Highstock contains Highcharts, so you don't have to include it twice.

Comment: Could you provide a link to development version of this app?

Comment: Wondering if you ever got this resolved Joe?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. Still no solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple issues.  What I did might not work for all circumstances.

I placed the highcharts require statements in a folder and file named after the view where I used it:

```
app/assets/
-javascripts
--foos
---foos.js
--application.js
```

foos.js contains:

```
//= require highcharts
//= require highcharts/modules/canvas-tools
//= require highcharts/modules/exporting
```

Answer (score 2):

I also have had this error-

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

To fix it I added this to line 2931-

```
CanVGRenderer = (typeof(Highcharts.CanVGRenderer) != "undefined"
    ? Highcharts.CanVGRenderer : {},
```

Since the extend function (line 128 of the highcharts.src.js) basically does the exact same thing when the variables get passed into it.

Also line 2897 in canvas-tools.src.js -

```
if (CanvasRenderingContext2D)
```

throws an error as well in IE. This section comes from canvg.js which was updated on may 7, 2013, but not updated by highcharts, and should now be -

```
if (typeof(CanvasRenderingContext2D) != 'undefined')
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the dev team:

> canvas-tools isn't supposed to be included in a script file. Instead, Highcharts lazy loads it on demand. See http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.canvasToolsURL.

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2311